# Measuring page processing time (serverside) of a web application

Tags: performance

When a user performs any action on a page, the request is sent to the server. The server processes the request and sends the files necessary to render the page to the client.

I want to track the time taken by the server for every page load, and log it to database for further analysis.

I calculated the time that each action takes on the serverside, but it doesn't truly correlate with the page. There can be multiple redirects before a page is rendered, and hence multiple actions, and it might change based on workflow and exceptions .

Basically, I want the total serverside execution time for the page just like YSlow  (without the queueing, latency and client side processing).

How do you track your server side speed? Anyone know of a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with this, but you could use a combination of ajax and server side metrics.  Log when the server side first starts executing and then have an ajax call fire when the page is done loading and subtract the two. It's somewhat dirty, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Apart from logging, you can use tools like Google Analytics which will give a total server time measured at the end user. To get more detail, you will need a tool like Dynatrace, AppDynamics, NewRelic etc.  that gives you a lot of details.
If you explain your server-side technology, Java, PHP, Ruby or ASP.net etc.  then a more targeted tool can be suggested.